# AngularJS - Directive inside a component doesn't bind stuff correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have redesigned one directive as a component. The trouble I've faced is my directive contains another directive which does process an event triggered in parent directive. All stuff was working well before I changed parent directive declaration to component. Take a look:

**Directive**:

```
app.directive("fileChange", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            fileChange: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('change', onChange);

            scope.$on('destroy', function () {
                element.off('change', onChange);
            });

            function onChange() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.fileChange();
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Component**:

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'myComponent.html',
    bindings: {
        imgSource: '@imgSrc'
    },
    controller: () => {
        function upload() {
            // doing something
            }

        this.upload = upload;
    }
});
```

**Template**:

```
<div>
    <img alt="image" class="img-preview" ng-src="{{$ctrl.imgSource}}"/>  
    <label class="btn">
        <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" file-change="$ctrl.upload();"/>
        Choose image
    </label>
</div>
```

So on, seems `$ctrl.upload()` doesn't fire the event or something like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: both component and directive are placed under the same module?

Comment: @LuninRoman yes, note that it is not absolutely new component. It is redesigned directive, that means it worked well before has been redesigned

Comment: Seems like there is some scope issue, Does {{$ctrl.imgSource}} works?

Comment: @Abhilasha yeah, it works as expected

Comment: The AngularJS scope destroy event is named `$destroy` prefixed with a dollar sign.

Comment: @georgeawg my logs. that solved, see the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'myComponent.html',
    bindings: {
        imgSource: '@imgSrc'
    },
    controller: function () {
        function upload() {
            // doing something
            }

        this.upload = upload;
    }
});
```

The problem is how you are using arrow function short syntax, take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

If you want to use short syntax it could be

```
  controller() {
  },
```

But the following syntax is intended for functions with return statement

```
elements.map(function(element) { 
  return element.length; 
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

elements.map(element => {
  return element.length;
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

While you return nothing in your controller, so it passed nothing as a component controller